# search a pattern in each line and append it at the end of that line

Tags: bash, vim, sed

I have a file with the following entries:

```
folder1/a_b.csv folder1/generated/
folder2/folder3/a_b1.csv folder12/generated/
folder4/b_c.csv folder123/generated/
folder5/d.csv folder1/new_folder/generated/
folder6/12.csv folder/anotherfolder/morefolder/evenmorefolder/generated/
```

I want to copy the csv file name from each line, paste them at the end of that line and append it with ".org". Hence, the changed file would look like

```
folder1/a_b.csv folder1/generated/a_b.csv.org
folder2/folder3/a_b1.csv folder12/generated/a_b1.csv.org
folder4/b_c.csv folder123/generated/b_c.csv.org
folder5/d.csv folder1/new_folder/generated/d.csv.org
folder6/12.csv folder/anotherfolder/morefolder/evenmorefolder/generated/12.csv.org
```

Basically, I am looking for a command in vim or sed using which I can **search a pattern in each line and append it at the end of that line**. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Vim

Here's how to do this in Vim:

```
:%s/\([^/]*\.csv\)\( .*\)/&\1.org/
```

This global (`:%`) *substitution* matches the filename (characters that don't contain `/`, ending in `.csv`), and captures `\(...\)` it. It then matches the rest of the line, and captures that, too.

As a replacement, first keep the original match `&` (or `\0`), then append the first capture (`\1`) with the additional suffix.

#### sed

Though the regular expression syntax is somewhat different than in Vim, the identical expression can be used with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/\([^/]*\.csv\)\( .*\)/&\1.org/' input
```

#### Alternatives

It looks like you want to do file renaming in batches. On Linux, the [mmv command-line tool](http://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html) is well suited for that; you'll probably find many similar tools on the web, too.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|/([^ ]*) .*|&\1.org|' file
```